# Deploy Lambda function to S3 bucket subdirectory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy a Lambda function to AWS from S3.

My organization currently does not provide the ability for me to upload files to the root of an S3 bucket, but only to a folder (ie: s3://application-code-bucket/Application1/).

Is there any way to deploy the Lambda function code through S3, from a directory other than the bucket root? I checked the documentation for Lambda's CreateFunction AWS command and could not find anything obvious.

Comment: There is no reason for it to be mentioned in the Lambda docs.  The argument is not a filename, it's an [object key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_FunctionCode.html#SSS-Type-FunctionCode-S3Key).  The fact that it can be in any "folder" should be implicit in this fact.

Comment: Michael- Would you like to create an answer? You are correct. I didn't recognize that S3Key referred to the 'object key'. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to zip your lambda package and upload to S3 in any folder.
2. You can then provide an https S3 url of the file to upload to lambda
   function.
3. The S3 bucket needs to be in the same region as that of the lambda
   function.
4. Make sure you zip from the folder, i.e when the package is unzipped,
   the files should be extracted in the same directory as the unzip
   command, and should not create a new directory for the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I have this old script of mine that I used to automate lambda deployments.
It needs to be refactored a bit, but still usable.

It gets as input the lambda name and the zip file path located locally on your PC.

It uploads it to S3 and publishes to the AWS Lambda.

- You need to set AWS credentials with IAM roles that allows:

  - S3 upload permission
  - AWS Lambda update permission
- You need to modify the bucket name and the path you want your zip to be uploaded to. (lines 36-37).

That's it.